# Draw on Desktop from WPF application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, draw

I would draw a rectangle on desktop from my WPF application. I've searched but i didn't find a good solution and a good example.
I would draw a rectangle at the edges of the screen and changes its color when something of specific happen.

How i can i do this in a correct way?

I found this code :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    IntPtr desktop = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktop)) {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
    ReleaseDC(desktop);
}
```

}

But i don't have a console application and i don't understand how i can re-paint / refresh my rectangle or change its color from this code.

thank all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a full screen WPF Application that has a transparent `Window`. You can find out how to do that from the [Creating Border-less Windows in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/creating-border-less-windows-in-wpf) page on Paul Sherrif's Blog. In short though, to get a borderless window, you need to set the following attributes on your `Window`:

> •`WindowStyle="None"`
>   •`ShowInTaskbar="False"`
>   •`AllowsTransparency="True"`
>   •`Background="Transparent"`

Then you simply do the drawing in the WPF Application, but it will *look like* the drawing is on the Desktop.

Comment: Ok i need that desktop continue to work normally. In this way it works?

Comment: Yes, this does not affect the Desktop in any way, but just looks as if it does.

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot be applied to WPF in any manner. WPF is a retained-mode API, unlike Windows Forms, so you can't draw it like this (actually you can use *HWND interop* or `DrawingVisual`). But it shouldn't bother you as you don't need to draw it by yourself, just declare required rectangles and any other stuff using XAML.

Comment: While I accept your general point, your answer is not strictly true. Graphics *can* still be drawn in this way using the `DrawingContext` class. See the *Drawing Content at the Visual Layer* section of the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. Of course, the user's *exact* code cannot be used in WPF.

Comment: @Sheridan I know, I did mention `DrawingVisual`, whose method `RenderOpen()` returns `DrawingContext`. Anyway, it's not GDI.